# What does `mac` in `utf8-mac` mean?

Tags: character-encoding

In Emacs, I show the newline convention used by emacs for the current file, by 
`M-x describe-variable`, then `buffer-file-coding-system`. The result is `utf8-mac`.

Does `mac`, `dos`, `unix` after the hyphen mean the newline convention only? or do they also give information about other things, beside the newline convention?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mac`, `dos` and `unix` only specify the newline convention.  `mac` stands for the (pre-OSX?) convention of CR only.

`utf-8-mac` should not be confused with `utf-8-nfd`, which is the UTF-8 variant that OSX uses for file names.  In it, non-ASCII characters are decomposed, so that for example `Ä` is stored as `A` followed by the combining version of `¨`.

Comment: is OSX the current OS on Mac computer?

Comment: Yes, or more properly "OS X". It was formerly known as "Mac OS X", being the tenth major version of "Mac OS", with a Roman numeral.